# How to Find and Replace text in the middle of a line using VI or other editors

Tags: string, replace, vi

---

I have a file with many lines.  I want to change the characters starting at a certain location on the line and keep all of the remainder of the line the same.

Ex.

line1 = 'aaaaaaaaiiiiiiiiiaaaiiii'

line2 = 'ababababiiiiiiiiiaaaiiii'

I want to keep all of the contents of the lines the same except for the "i" in this example.  I would like to change the "i" to "2"

line1 = 'aaaaaaaa222222222aaaiiii'

line2 = 'abababab222222222aaaiiii'

Comment: You can try the below command, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:%s/i/2/g
```

That code, will replace all occurrences of "i" by "2"

For further details: http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/emacs/vi_search_replace.html

Comment: thanks for comments.  I was not clear as I made a mistake.  Please see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
line1 = 'aaaaaaaaiiiiiiiiiaaa'

line2 = 'ababababiiiiiiiiiaaa'

File name = testfile.txt
```

Command:-

```
sed -i 's/i/2/g' testfile.txt
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for comments.  I was not clear as I made a mistake.  Please see my updates.